# How to fit an image according to screen size

Tags: html, css

Let's say we have image with 2000px width & 500px height in css property. For a 1080p monitor how can I configure this image properly. I want this image to be set on any screen size for responsive design.

Comment: Calculate aspect ratio: 2000:500 -> 4:1 ratio
Then use the 100%:25% in css

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you want to keep aspect ratio then put width:100% and height:auto

if you want to cover whole parent element then height:100% and width:100%

Answer (score 19):

This is what you want:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

If you want your image to be scaled differently (or add/override certain styles for more responsivenss) in different devices you need to use CSS media queries. Eg.

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%; // Show 4 images in a row normally
    height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  img {
    width: 100%; // Override width to show only one image in a row on smaller screens
  }
}
```

[Mozilla Documentation on CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

[W3Schools tutorial on CSS media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)