# how to make a picture stretchable when window is enlarging by width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to make the "img/rsz_indexpage_image.jpg" picture stretchable according to the div size variation.when enlarging the width of the div picture  is not enlages as expected.how to do this by bootstrap. now image size is static when enlarging.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>     
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loginjs.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/logincss.css">

</head>
   <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row vertical-offset-100">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">                                
                                <div class="row-fluid user-row">
                                    <img src="img/rsz_indexpage_image.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Conxole Admin"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" class="form-signin">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <label class="panel-login">
                                            <div class="login_result"></div>
                                        </label>
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" type="text">
                                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" type="password">
                                        <br></br>
                                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" id="login" value="Login »">
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please upload js fiddle here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to keep aspect ratio then put width:100% and height:auto

if you want to cover whole parent element then height:100% and width:100%

and its on you how you put it with .img-responsive

[img-responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555326/how-to-fit-an-image-according-to-screen-size/30555433#30555433)

```
.img-responsive { 
   display: block; 
   width: 100%; 
   height: auto; 
   margin: auto; 
}
```

Comment: .img-responsive {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
  updateImageSize()
};

function updateImageSize() {
    $(".img-responsive").each(function(){
        var ratio_cont = jQuery(this).width()/jQuery(this).height();
        var $img = jQuery(this).find("img");
        var ratio_img = $img.width()/$img.height();
        if (ratio_cont > ratio_img)
        {
            $img.css({"width": "100%", "height": "auto"});
        }
        else if (ratio_cont < ratio_img)
        {
            $img.css({"width": "auto", "height": "100%"});
        }
    }); 
};
```